# Overriding Form.Text property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, properties

I'm attempting to override [Form.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159419.aspx) in order to modify the `Title` prior to appearing on the form.

As a proof of concept I created this class, which will be used in place of directly inheriting from `Form`:

```
public class FormWithVersionNumber : Form
{
    [SettingsBindable(true)]
    public override string Text
    { 
        get
        {
            return "tester";
        }

    }
}
```

I would've expected all forms that inherit from this to have the Title `"tester"` but instead it is always blank.  I've been through with breakpoints, and can't see any reason why this should happen.  So what is the reason?

Comment: Check this part [*When overriding the Text property in a derived class, use the base class's Text property to extend the base implementation. Otherwise, you must provide all the implementation. You are not required to override both the get and set accessors of the Text property; you can override only one if needed.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.text.aspx)

Comment: So you should be using `base.Text` to set the value and then return the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the actual `Title` is not retreived from `Text` but from the internal property `WindowText` in `Control`.

Here's an example of how you can do:

```
public partial class FormWithVersionNumber : Form
{
    public override sealed string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text + " 1.0.0.0";
        }
        set
        {
            base.Text = value + " 1.0.0.0";
        }
    }


    public FormWithVersionNumber()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Text = "Some Title";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Filip - the problem is I'd still like to be able to set the title in the derived class, which this doesn't seem to enable (it's just ignored)

Comment: @m.edmondson, Why not set it in the constructor?